# ASP.Net Identity Role restricted database entries

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have been making changes to my project to incorporate ASP.Net Identity.
Right now I have come to a halt of a specific problem.
I have a model called Files, and I must be able to add files that only users on a specific role can see.
Let's say I add a report that is only intended for Developers, Testers and Administrators, but HumanResources and Accounting shouldn't be seeing that entry.

I specified my model like this:

```
public class FileModel
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "File Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(280)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Filetype { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Path { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Allowed Users")]
    public virtual List<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

My expectation is that I would be able to add Roles to the file, but even though I specified a List of IdentityRole in the model, the mapping from FileModel and Roles was never created in the database when I migrated it, and there is no mention of Roles in the FileModel table. Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add Role column and after that you just may compare your users with filemodel

```
    ......
    [Required]
    public string RoleId{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public IdentityRole Roles{ get; set; }
```

Or you can create an intermediate table with two ForeignKeys - FilemodelId and RoleId